# Cannot print from Java application on Samba printer, but can on network printer

Tags: printing, samba

I have strange problem with printing from Ubuntu, and cannot figure how to solve it.

Running some custom Java application on Ubuntu 12.04, and it have to print some of the content.

It can print without any problem if it prints on network printer, but printing in stopped when try to print on Samba shared printer (it drops blank page).

In any case, test page can be printed also without any problem.

I was thinking that problem is in java application, but in that case printing will be impossible in both cases (again, it can print on network printer).

I have checked logs, but found no error at all in any case.

It's HP printer HP LaserJet P2015.

Can you give me some ideas where can be a problem? Thank you in advance!

**UPDATE:** just to add, that I have some feeling that there is some problem with Java application, or it's setup. Because, in case when printing is made on network printer (case when everything works), applications send response (message window) that printing is done. In other case, when printing is made to printer attached on Windows, I don't get any response, and it prints only one blank page. But again, printing printer's test pages in any case works well.